# How to add new point to Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polyline

I am using Leaflet Map and extension called [Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline](https://github.com/hgoebl/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline) to draw a multicolor polyline.

(here some demos: http://hgoebl.github.io/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/demo/)

So I can use a code to create the polyline:

```
L.multiOptionsPolyline(points, {
    multiOptions: {
        optionIdxFn: function (latLng) {
            var i,
                altThresholds = [800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500];

            for (i = 0; i < altThresholds.length; ++i) {
                if (latLng.alt <= altThresholds[i]) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return altThresholds.length;
        },
        options: [
            {color: '#0000FF'}, {color: '#0040FF'}, {color: '#0080FF'},
            {color: '#00FFB0'}, {color: '#00E000'}, {color: '#80FF00'},
            {color: '#FFFF00'}, {color: '#FFC000'}, {color: '#FF0000'}
        ]
    },
    weight: 5,
    lineCap: 'butt',
    opacity: 0.75,
    smoothFactor: 1}).addTo(map);
```

When adding points on create I am using something like:

```
[{"lat":lat,"lng":lon,"alt":altitude},{"lat":lat,"lng":lon,"alt":altitude}]
```

**However I got stuck trying to add a new point to an existing polyline**.
In leaflet it was easy:

```
polyline.addLatLng([lat, lon]);
```

**...but how to do that with Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline?**

PS. I've also tried to ask the author however after 1 year I am still without the answer:
https://github.com/hgoebl/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/hgoebl/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/blob/master/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline.js#L24), [here](https://github.com/hgoebl/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/blob/master/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline.js#L81) and [here](https://github.com/hgoebl/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/blob/master/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline.js#L83), MultiOptionsPolyline is just a FeatureGroup of Polylines, so you can add another polyline like this

```
var group = L.multiOptionsPolyline(points, {...

var polyline = L.polyline([
    [47.747263, 12.24906],
    [47.75, 12.3]
], {weight: 5, lineCap: "butt", opacity: 0.75, smoothFactor: 1, color: "#FF0000"});

group.addLayer(polyline);
```

but, of course, you will have to calculate its color based on the logic implemented in optionIdxFn and options.